# What is the right model of this set?

Tags: analysis, logic, foundations, nonstandard-models

I am doing a research in foundation of maths, especially in logic area. Right now, I am building a set $\mathbb{L}$ through this five axioms:

1. Additive axiom: closeness, commutative, associative, 0 as identity, additive inverse.
2. Multiplicative axiom: closeness, commutative, associative, 1 as identity, multiplicative inverse.
3. Distributive axiom.
4. Total partial order axiom: reflexive, transitivity, anti-symmetry, totality.
5. Existence of positive infinitesimal.

As you might noticed already, axioms 1-4 are just like axioms in reals. The only addition in here is axiom 5, which make everything be much more complicated.

My problem for now is I want to prove that $\mathbb{L}$ is consistent and therefore, semantically, I need to provide a model for it. Can you help me with it? I have been thinking about this for weeks and still cannot come up with a right one. I thought $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ with a lexicographic order would be a right model, but unfortunately, I didn't think it is. Cheers!

Comment: You should read about non-standard analysis. More specific Robinson and Los' work.

Comment: Hi Asaf. Thank for your reply. I did read it from Rob Glodblatt's book. But I don't think it helps me much in answering my question. :-(

Comment: Note that "existence of positive infinitesimal" is not a first-order statement without further clarification, unlike 1-4 which seem to be axioms for an ordered field.  Robinson's approach constructs a model of an ordered field in which infinitesimals exist, so in that respect, Asaf's suggestion is quite relevant.

Comment: @hardmath and Asaf, just clarifying, when you talked about Robinson's approach, did you guys mean hyperreals?

Comment: That is a term, [hyperreal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number), used by some authors, yes.

Comment: Ah yes I learnt about it. But I guess hyperreals cannot be a model of my set $\mathbb{L}$, right?

Comment: @AngghaNugraha: There are various notions of "infinitesimal", and *you've not defined* what you mean by that term.  If you mean what Robinson et al mean by infinitesimal, then the "hyperreals" are a model of your axioms.

Comment: @AngghaNugraha Why aren't the hyperreals a model of your statements?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Hmm, because of the multiplicative inverse axiom?

Comment: Intuitively the reciprocal of something "infinitely small" is something "infinitely large".  This is so with hyperreal numbers.

Comment: @hardmath: Yes indeed! So suppose that $\epsilon$ is our infinitesimal number. Then its reciprocal, $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ is an infinite number. But the problem is: will $\epsilon.\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ be equal with one?

Comment: @AngghaNugraha That is incorrect. The hyperreals **do** have multiplicative inverses: in particular, the answer to your question is "yes," $\epsilon\cdot {1\over \epsilon}=1$. In the hyperreals you have "coherent" infinities. The hyperreals are an example of a **non-Archimedean ordered field**, and any such will satisfy your axioms.

Comment: @NoahSchweber One should be a bit careful about where the model begins and ends here. The hyperreals see themselves as Archimedean. This is not inconsistent because to them the natural numbers include the infinite hypernaturals, and every infinitesimal hyperreal is less than the reciprocal of some hypernatural.

Comment: Typo: every positive hyperreal is larger than the reciprocal of some hypernatural (not smaller)

Comment: @Ian: sure, the first-order theory of the hyperreals is that same as that of the reals, even if you throw in a predicate to detect natural numbers, but I think the OP is thinking about a first-order set theory, where one can see through the hypernatural charade.

Comment: @AngghaNugraha I don't understand your question. Can you clarify why you think the hyperreals aren't a model of your axioms?

Comment: @Ian: Did you mean it's about internal set and external set?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Yes you're right. I just realised that $\mathbb{^*R}$ is a model for it.

Comment: @RobArthan Sure, but it is still useful to be able to look at the hyperreals "from inside" (since this is why the transfer principle holds, in a sense) and "from outside" (since this tells you why the hyperreals are not the same as the reals).

Comment: @AngghaNugraha That's how it manifests when you construct the hyperreals using Nelson's internal set theory. What I was describing was more directly related to the Robinson construction, in which the hyperreals are a nonstandard model of the first order theory of the reals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing are precisely the **non-Archimedean ordered fields**. ("Non-Archimedean" refers to the existence of infinitesimals and infinite elements; the "ordered field" bit covers the rest.)

There are lots of these (e.g., continuum-many non-isomorphic countable examples). One way to construct them is via **ultrapowers**: fix a nonprincipal ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on a set $I$, and let $$\prod_I\mathbb{R}/\mathcal{U}$$ be the set of maps $I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, thought of as $I$-length sequences of reals, modulo the equivalence relation $$(a_i)_{i\in I}\sim (b_i)_{i\in I}\iff \{i: a_i=b_i\}\in\mathcal{U}.$$ This is a set, and we can define an ordering $<$ and operations $+$ and $\times$ on it in the obvious way (we have to check that this is well-defined, but this is not hard and a good exercise). The resulting object is a non-Archimedean (since $\mathcal{U}$ is nonprincipal) ordered field.

In fact, the ordered field $\prod_I\mathbb{R}/\mathcal{U}$ is an *elementary extension* of the ordered field of real numbers; this is (an instance of) Los' Theorem. So, among other things, it is a *real closed* field, and its first-order theory is computable.

---

As far as *examples* of these things go: there are natural examples of non-Archimedean ordered fields, such as fields of power series (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Ring_structure).

Answer (score 1):

Ultrapowers and power series are **not** needed to give an example of a non-archimedean ordered field. Let $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ denote the ring of polynomials in the indeterminate $x$ over the rational numbers $\Bbb{Q}$. Then the field of rational functions $\Bbb{Q}\{x\} = \{ \frac{f}{g} \mathrel{|} f, g \in \Bbb{Q}[x], g \neq 0\}$ can be ordered in such a way that $x < \frac{1}{n}$ for every positive integer $n$. Then $\Bbb{Q}\{x\}$ is a non-archimedean ordered field (and every non-archimedean ordered field has a sub-ordered-field isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}\{x\}$).